# beforeinstallprompt in not firing without clicking on A2HS button

Tags: javascript, service-worker, progressive-web-apps

I have index.html page in which i am using below code:-

```
<script>
  window.addEventListener("beforeinstallprompt", function(e) {
    console.log('ritwik', 'test message to be shown');
  });
</script>
```

I have service worker file which works perfectly. When i click on Add to Home Screen the A2HS banner is shown but i want to show it with a button click on desktop.

Comment: That is writing a message to the console in the dev tools, not a popup button. You are not seeing that in the console?

Comment: No, I am not seeing in console. i see the console mesage only when i go in application > add to home screen

Comment: What device & Browser are you testing on?

Comment: Is that a HTTPS URL and you tested it with the Chrome Dev Audit tool (Progressive Web App) AND you see the message "User may be prompted to install web app"?

Comment: yes it is HTTPS URL and PWA audit is 100%

Comment: What device & Browser are you testing on? Have you removed previous installs completely and cleared the cache?

Comment: I am testing it on Desktop and chrome.Yes!

Comment: Sorry, just to be sure. You do not see your Icon here? chrome://apps/

Comment: Also you may want to have someone with another machine that has not accessed the URL, try on their machine.

Comment: Your problem is that the beforeinstallprompt event is not triggered on chrome desktop unless you click on the Add to home screen link in dev tools. Am I undestanding it correctly? This is because PWA is still a beta feature on chrome desktop. you can enable it with the flag : chrome://flags/#enable-desktop-pwas

Comment: yes now you understood my problem. ok.

Comment: Thank You! It's working but i will have to add manual button. then that triggers not automatically.

Comment: @Mathias, When i am preventing beforeInstallprompt on android mobile device it is not preventing to propmpt with below code:-
window.addEventListener('beforeinstallprompt', (event) => {
        event.preventDefault();
      });
would you suggest what is correct behaviour? I have seen this on google site that "The mini-infobar will appear when the site meets the add to home screen criteria, regardless of whether you preventDefault() on the beforeinstallprompt event or not."

Comment: Yes - this is currently a temporary "feature" in the most recent version of chrome. Nothing I know of that we can do until the next major release. I believe they will eventually get rid of the snack bar from showing. If you are on Twitter, follow @petele. He seems to be the one to keep people informed about changes.

Comment: Thanks @Mathias!